# Getting 'numPlay is not defined' error in React for button click method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call nextPage() in the getConfirm when somebody clicks the button "Confirm", but it says that numPlay is never defined in the getConfirm() method.

Please someone help me understand why/fix it! Thank you

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

const title = 
    <h1 style={{ fontSize: "40px" }}>
        Draft
    </h1>

const numPlayers = (
    <div id="numPlayers">
        {title}
        <h1 style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}>
            How many players would you like to draft with?
        </h1>
        <input id="numPlay" placeholder="Number of players" type="number"></input>
        <div>
        </div>
        <button id="confirm" onClick={getConfirm}>
            Confirm
        </button>
    </div>
);

function getConfirm() {
    var numPlay = document.getElementById("numPlay");
    root.render(nextPage);
}

const nextPage = (
    <div>
        {title}
        <h1 style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}>
            How many draftees are there?
            {numPlay}
        </h1>
    </div>
)

root.render(numPlayers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `numPlay` outside of `getCOnfirm`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

const title = <h1 style={{ fontSize: '40px' }}>Draft</h1>;
let numPlay;
const numPlayers = (
  <div id="numPlayers">
    {title}
    <h1 style={{ fontSize: '20px' }}>
      How many players would you like to draft with?
    </h1>
    <input id="numPlay" placeholder="Number of players" type="number"></input>
    <div></div>
    <button id="confirm" onClick={getConfirm}>
      Confirm
    </button>
  </div>
);

function getConfirm() {
  numPlay = document.getElementById('numPlay');
  root.render(nextPage);
}

const nextPage = (
  <div>
    {title}
    <h1 style={{ fontSize: '20px' }}>
      How many draftees are there?
      {numPlay}
    </h1>
  </div>
);

root.render(numPlayers);
```

But why are you using React by calling `.render` imperatively, are you trying to integrate some React components on an already existing SPA?

Comment: Thanks! And for your question about calling .render, what is the superior way? I am just starting so thank you :D

Comment: If you are starting to learn React, start from here https://en.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html, then go down a follow all the points from 4 to 12 . Those are the React core concepts. Once you grasp them you are already ready to go and build your first components. SInce you start now just focus on Functional components and Hooks, you can jump classes.